# Normalizing Image Descriptor OpenCV Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, sift

Hi I'm going to implement the Opencv BOW algorithm in OpenCV Java. I tried to convert most of the code into java. But I'm stuck here as I do not understand what is really going on here.

```
void BOWImgDescriptorExtractor::compute( InputArray keypointDescriptors, OutputArray _imgDescriptor, std::vector<std::vector<int> >* pointIdxsOfClusters )
{
int clusterCount = descriptorSize(); // = vocabulary.rows

// Match keypoint descriptors to cluster center (to vocabulary)
std::vector<DMatch> matches;
dmatcher->match( keypointDescriptors, matches );

// Compute image descriptor
if( pointIdxsOfClusters )
{
    pointIdxsOfClusters->clear();
    pointIdxsOfClusters->resize(clusterCount);
}

_imgDescriptor.create(1, clusterCount, descriptorType());
_imgDescriptor.setTo(Scalar::all(0));

Mat imgDescriptor = _imgDescriptor.getMat();

float *dptr = imgDescriptor.ptr<float>();
for( size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
{
    int queryIdx = matches[i].queryIdx;
    int trainIdx = matches[i].trainIdx; // cluster index
    CV_Assert( queryIdx == (int)i );

    dptr[trainIdx] = dptr[trainIdx] + 1.f;
    if( pointIdxsOfClusters )
        (*pointIdxsOfClusters)[trainIdx].push_back( queryIdx );
}

// Normalize image descriptor.
imgDescriptor /= keypointDescriptors.size().height;
}
```

In the final line it says, normalizing descriptor. I want to know how to implement that part in java. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It just divides every element in `imgDescriptor` by the number of keypoints

Comment: Thank you miki, I'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do like you,but it doesn't work fine for me,so i've built opencv2.9 with bow trainer fonctionnality,it works Well and i've 96℅ of précision